# SQL Concatenating distinct values from multiple columns into one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this 3 columns tab

```
 PRODUCT....CATEGORY......CLASS
 X............1.............II
 Y............1.............II
 Z............1.............II
 Y............2.............II
```

And I want to return a single row with all DISTINCT values of each column:

```
 RESULT

 X Y Z 1 2 II
```

What's the best way to get this result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there are no duplicates between the columns, you can use `group_concat()`:

```
select concat_ws(' ',
                 group_concat(distinct product separator ' '),
                 group_concat(distinct category separator ' '),
                 group_concat(distinct class separator ' ')
                )
from tab t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first collect all values in a subselect and then show these values with [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
select group_concat(v separator ' ')
from (select product as v from testa
      union
      select category as v from testa
      union
      select class as v from testa) t
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/321a8f/3/0)